# Why are my attributes showing out of position order on Magento 1.9.1.0 frontend?

Tags: attributes

The size attribute options on my configurable products are not displaying in the correct position on the frontend. They are displaying in the order of product ID instead

I have set the position on the size attribute in the admin panel (i.e. XS is position 1, S is position 2), but this appears to be disregarded on shop frontend.

Is this a known error? How do I fix this?

Comment: This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270918/magento-1-9-1-not-sorting-configurable-product-attributes-dropdown-by-position/28867699#28867699

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have it set correctly. In the admin go to System -> Index Management and select all, reindex, submit.  This will update the catalog data in the database with any changes you have made.  Then go to System -> Cache Management and be sure to Flush Magento Cache, Flush Cache Storage, and select all-refresh-submit.

Note: Magento has its own [stackexchange site](https://magento.stackexchange.com/) for questions. Its best to post Magento questions there vs stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I was on there earlier, must have posted in wrong tab! I've already reindexed and flushed all caches.